# How to give user inputs to detect a specific color from video in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, color-detection

I have written a code in python to detect a red color in OpenCV. I am getting proper output,but I want to give user input in the code to detect a specific color. Eg: If I will give blue as a user input, it should show only blue on the output. I also want to add few attributes as a output, such as time of that object get detected and location of the live video. I am new to python and opencv, it would be great if I will get some guidance.

My existing code is as below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Capture the input frame from webcam
def get_frame(cap, scaling_factor):
    # Capture the frame from video capture object
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Resize the input frame
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=scaling_factor,
            fy=scaling_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    return frame

if __name__=='__main__':
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    scaling_factor = 0.5

    # Iterate until the user presses ESC key
    while True:
        frame = get_frame(cap, scaling_factor)

        # Convert the HSV colorspace
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        # Define 'blue' range in HSV colorspace
        lower = np.array([60,100,100])
        upper = np.array([180,255,255])

        # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue color
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

        # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
        res = cv2.medianBlur(res, 5)

        cv2.imshow('Original image', frame)
        cv2.imshow('Color Detector', res)

        # Check if the user pressed ESC key
        c = cv2.waitKey(5)
        if c == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have a look at this link https://data-flair.training/blogs/project-in-python-colour-detection/amp/ The dataset used in this could be used. For any color you will obtain it's RGB values from the dataset and convert to HSV and check for a particular range.

Comment: This project doesn't have answers I am looking for. I need to give user input of specific color and will be able to detect only that color in the output. I don't know how to write that function.

Comment: @nathancy The script you mentioned is helpful. Thank you for that. Is there any script where I can calculate the timing of object's appearance in my live video. Eg: Initially there is no one in the video and as soon as someone came in, I have to calculate the timing of that object until it's gone from the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work correctly. Looking at the equations about converting [from RGB to HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_RGB) bearing in mind that boundaries in OpenCV are between 0-180 for `H` channel and 0-255 for `S` and `V` channels, we can generalize the code to work for all colors.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Capture the input frame from webcam
def get_frame(cap, scaling_factor):
    # Capture the frame from video capture object
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Resize the input frame
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=scaling_factor,
            fy=scaling_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    return frame

# Define the color range in HSV colorspace
lower1 = np.array([0,100,100])
upper1 = np.array([60,255,255])
lower2 = np.array([120,100,100])
upper2 = np.array([180,255,255])
def color_range(degree):
    # Degree is between 0-360
    # OpenCV uses 0-180 range for H channel
    degree = int(degree/2);
    global lower1, upper1, lower2, upper2
    if degree < 60:
        lower1 = np.array([int(0),100,100])
        upper1 = np.array([degree+60,255,255])
        lower2 = np.array([degree+120,100,100])
        upper2 = np.array([int(180),255,255])
    elif degree > 120:
        lower1 = np.array([degree-60,100,100])
        upper1 = np.array([int(180),255,255])
        lower2 = np.array([int(0),100,100])
        upper2 = np.array([degree-120,255,255])
    else:
        lower1 = np.array([degree-60,100,100])
        upper1 = np.array([degree+60,255,255])
        # ineffective variables
        lower2 = np.array([181,100,100])
        upper2 = np.array([181,255,255])

if __name__=='__main__':
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    scaling_factor = 0.5

    # create trackbar for color change
    winname = 'Color Detector'
    cv2.namedWindow(winname)
    cv2.createTrackbar('Color', winname, 0, 360, color_range)

    # Iterate until the user presses ESC key
    while True:
        frame = get_frame(cap, scaling_factor)

        # Convert the HSV colorspace
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        # Threshold the HSV image to get only desired color
        mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower1, upper1)
        mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower2, upper2)
        mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)

        # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

        cv2.imshow('Original image', frame)
        cv2.imshow(winname, res)

        # Check if the user pressed ESC key
        c = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if c == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
```